# What is the Esperanto word for “hype”?

Tags: single-word-requests

My best guesses are *“eksciti(ĝi)”* and *“furori(gi)”*. Are those good enough or am I way off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The radical *furor-* seems a good starting point to me. Sometimes "hype" has this meaning of exaggeration. This can be expressed by "tro-" as prefix.

> Ĉu la sukceso de Duolingo estas dauripova aŭ nur trofurora.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider *distrumpetado* ("widespread trumpeting"), *(dis)famigego* ("great (broad) promotion"), *tamtamado, misfuroro, reklamaĉegaro,* etc, limited only by your knack for metaphor and tolerance for lexical whimsy.